# Javascript recursion (Tree- Structure)

Tags: javascript

I have the following json :

```
var jsonObj = [
              {
                       "parentIndex": '0'  ,
                       "childIndex": '3'  ,
                       "parent": "ROOT",
                       "child": "root3"
               },
               {
                      "parentIndex": '3'  ,
                      "childIndex": '2'  ,
                      "parent": "root3" ,
                      "child": "root2"
               },
               {
                       "parentIndex": '3'  ,
                       "childIndex": '1'  ,
                       "parent": "root3" ,
                       "child": "root1"
               }
               ];
```

I need to convert the above json to a Tree-structure using **Recursion** in **Javascript**. The Tree-structure would look like :

```
nodeStructure: {
        text: { name: "root3" },
        children: [
            {
                text: { name: "root2" }
            },
            {
                text: { name: "root1" }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Comment: is the data sorted? do you have tried something?

Comment: The data doesnt require sorting (sorting isnt required in output as well). This was just a sample data.

Comment: why do you need a recursion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use following code:

```
var jsonObj = [
          {
                   "parentIndex": '0'  ,
                   "childIndex": '3'  ,
                   "parent": "ROOT",
                   "child": "root3"
           },
           {
                  "parentIndex": '3'  ,
                  "childIndex": '2'  ,
                  "parent": "root3" ,
                  "child": "root2"
           },
           {
                   "parentIndex": '3'  ,
                   "childIndex": '1'  ,
                   "parent": "root3" ,
                   "child": "root1"
           }
           ];

function filter(array,condition){
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if(condition(array[i])){
      result.push(array[i]);
    }
  }
  return result;
}


function getChilds(parentKey,items){
  var subItems =  filter(items,function(n){return n.parent === parentKey});
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < subItems.length; i++) {
    var subItem = subItems[i];
    var resultItem = {
      text: {name:subItem.child}
    };
    var kids = getChilds(subItem.child , items);
    if(kids.length){
      resultItem.children = kids;
    }
    result.push(resultItem);
  }
  return result;
}


var rootItems = getChilds('ROOT',jsonObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a single loop approach with a temporary object for collecting all nodes and the result object, wich returns the node which is the root node.

```js
var data = [{ parentIndex: '0', childIndex: '3', parent: "ROOT", child: "root3" }, { parentIndex: '3', childIndex: '2', parent: "root3", child: "root2" }, { parentIndex: '3', childIndex: '1', parent: "root3", child: "root1" }],
    tree = function (data, root) {
        var r, o = {};
        data.forEach(function (a) {
            o[a.childIndex] = { text: { name: a.child } };
            if (o[a.childIndex] && o[a.childIndex].children) {
                o[a.childIndex].children = o[a.childIndex].children;
            }
            if (a.parentIndex === root) {
                r = o[a.childIndex];
            } else {
                o[a.parentIndex] = o[a.parentIndex] || {};
                o[a.parentIndex].children = o[a.parentIndex].children || [];
                o[a.parentIndex].children.push(o[a.childIndex]);
            }
        });
        return r;
    }(data, '0');

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```